# Android: Handle Onclick Listerner in included layout

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I have a layout I am trying to use onclick on the views in the second layout:

```
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/activity_main" />
    <include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

the second is obvoiously meant to be a bottom sheet.. the thing is the views inside are not working when I am implementing `View.OnClickListener`

the onClick looks like this:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.lob_tv:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, LOBActivity.class));
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left);
                break;
            case R.id.project_tv:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, ProjectActivity.class));
              //  overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left);
                break;
            case R.id.rep_tv:
                break;
            case R.id.designation_tv:
                break;
            default:
                break
              }
```

the onclick however is not working how do I do this...I can find all the views individually but I don't understand why this is not working, also I want to keep the bottom sheet open when I return back to the activity as well. I think I need to open the main activty with an intent and extras to know if the user is opening the main activity for the first time or is returning from another activity.

Comment: maybe you forgot to add your onClickListener to your view in this way: yourView.setOnClickListener(this)

Comment: that was what I was missing thanks reza